# twitter-bootstrap-rails gem not installing in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I've just created a new rails application and I am trying to run `rails g bootstrap:install` from my terminal but my terminal returns this...

Why might this be? I am running rails 4.1.6 and I have bundled all the necessary gems. My only thought would be that the gem hasn't been updated?

```
/Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223:in `class_eval': /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223: `@@{' is not allowed as a class variable name
/Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
    unless defined? @@{:instance_writer=>true}
                      ^ (SyntaxError)
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223:in `block in cattr_reader'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:222:in `each'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:222:in `cattr_reader'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:258:in `cattr_accessor'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/cache.rb:155:in `<class:Store>'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/cache.rb:154:in `<module:Cache>'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/cache.rb:14:in `<module:ActiveSupport>'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/cache.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/jbuilder-2.2.4/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/jbuilder-2.2.4/lib/jbuilder/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/jbuilder-2.2.4/lib/jbuilder.rb:318:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
from /Users/sambelton/Documents/Masters Work/Advanced Web Application Development/boxintheair/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:140:in `serve'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/sambelton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This isn't really a bootstrap issue, but instead another gem you have installed seems to be having problems. The `aws-s3` gem version `0.6.3` by the look of the error messages. Perhaps try reinstalling that gem, or remove it from your `Gemfile` and try the command again?

Comment: Thanks, it seems that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't you wanna https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/ ?
It works fine with rails.